# node.js http server: how to get pending socket connections?

Tags: node.js, sockets, http

on a basic node http server like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

  console.log("number of concurr. connections: " + this.getConnections());
  //var pendingConnections = ???

});

server.maxConnections = 500;

server.listen(4000);
```

if i send 500 requests at one time to the server, the number of concurr. connections is arround 350. with the hard limit set to 500 (`net.server.backlog` too), i want to know, how to access the number of pending connections (max. 150 in this example) when ever a new request starts.

so i think i have to access the underlying socket listening on port 4000 to get this info, but until now i was not able to get it.

**EDIT**

looking at node-http there is an event called `connection`, so i think the roundtrip of an request is as follows:

1. client connects to server socket --> 3-way-handshake, socket lasts in state `CONNECTED` (or `ESTABLISHED` ?!) then in node event `connection` is emitted.
2. the node http server accepts this pending connection an starts processing the request by emitting `request`

so the number of connections has to be at least as big as the number of requests, but with following example i could not confirm this:

```
var http = require('http');

var activeRequets = 0;
var activeConnections = 0;

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){

    activeRequests++;
    res.send("foo");

});

server.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.setKeepAlive(false);
    activeConnections++;

});

setInterval(function(){

    console.log("activeConns: " + activeConnections + " activeRequests: " + activeRequests);
    activeRequests = 0;
    activeConnections = 0;

}, 500);

server.maxConnections = 1024;
server.listen(4000, '127.0.0.1');
```

even if i stress the server with 1000 concurr connections and adding one delay in the response, `activeRequests` is mostly as high as `activeConnections`. even worse, the activeRequests are often higher then activeconnections, how could this be?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC You can just count how many connections that have a status of SYN_RECV for that particular IP and port that you're listening on. Whether you use a child process to execute netstat and grep (or similar utilities) for that information, or write a binding to get this information using the *nix C API, is up to you.

Comment: good point. so i need to know how big the current accept queue is. for my understanding, a client connetcs to the server socket, the 3-way handshake is done and then, the socket lasts in state `SYN_RECV` until the application layer (http server) accepts this socket to process the request, or am i wrong?

Comment: i've got doubts, cause if i read  `netstat -an` continiously, there are nearly no (or at least 1-2) `SYN_RECV`. could it be, that an socket is in state `CONNECTED` as long as the application layer hasnt accepted it? cause in http (except the `keep-alive` option) each request = new socket.